# What do the symbols on the mummy's face mean?

Tags: mummy-2017

In The Mummy 2017, the title character has symbols written on her face. I assume that they are ancient Egyptian hyroglyphics and that the people who made the movie chose specific words to write on her face. **What do the symbols translate to in English?**

Here is a link to a photo:

[image: This is an animated gif which shows a close-up of Ahmanet, the title character from the movie The Mummy (2017). The face is covered with unknown symbols, which identification is the purpose of this question. Some noticeable details are the fact that ashes seem to be flying over her face, along with the iris of her eyes growing darker and bigger and shrinking back to normal size periodically.]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I asked my good friend Elizabeth (Lizzie) Yianni-Georgiou where she got these symbols from and what they mean. She confirmed that they were ancient Sumerian symbols and that they reflect an incantation from the Egyptian Book of the Dead

> **Q.** *What language are the symbols on Sofia Boutella's face and body? Is it Egyptian or some other alphabet? https://tinyurl.com/y9attmza*
>
> **A.** *Language is ancient Sumerian. It's from the incantation Ahmanet reads from the Book of the Dead, calling on Set, God of
> death/underworld.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/874686896693268482)</sup></sub>

---

She's confirmed this in a number of interviews.

> *The writing on Ahmanet's body comes from the ancient Egyptian funerary
> text Book of the Dead and "**the incantation asking the dead to come and
> help her,**" explains the makeup artist of the lines of symbols running
> from Ahmanet's face down to her legs and feet. Yianni-Georgiou used
> the MAC Penultimate Eye Liner as a stylus to create the prominent
> black writing, marks and lines.*
>
> *For inspiration, the makeup artist studied mummies in museums and followed the backstories included in the script. "I had to take into consideration the stories that [director] Alex Kurtzman and the other guys had written to develop her and bring her to life." (Or undeath, as the case may be.)*
>
> *Yianni-Georgiou added blue color to Ahmanet's fingertips, too, because she "wanted to keep her slightly tribal." The inspiration for that came from Tutankhamun himself, she said. "He had gold fingers and toe covers. So I took that and made blue finger dip to give her a slightly more tribalesque feel and then on her hand, she's got this writing about how she's due to become the queen, which we took from **ancient Egyptian** to tell that part of the story."*
>
> <sub><sup>[WHAT ARE THOSE LETTERS ON 'THE MUMMY'? MAKEUP ARTIST TALKS TRANSFORMING SOFIA BOUTELLA IN THE FILM](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/mummy-makeup-artist-transforming-sofia-boutella-1010890)</sup></sub>

and

> ***"The raised runes all over her body come from the "Book of the Dead" so
> they do actually say something"***

Note that these "runes" are *highly stylised* (to the point of being unrecognisable), appear to have been applied semi-randomly and bear very little resemblance to either Sumerian or Egyptian writings.

Since the original Book of the Dead was written in Egyptian and has been converted into Sumerian, it seems that the writing is going to be **untranslatable on a direct basis.**

[image]

Comment: We imagined that the symbols actually say something and you confirm. However, the OP asks **WHAT** the symbols say. The makeup artist is not the best source. Someone else chose the symbols for the makeup artist, and that someone else is a better source.

Comment: @CodeMed - The interview indicates that the makeup artist chose the writing to apply. The actual symbols appear to be highly stylised and I'm struggling to see how they correspond with any known Egyptian writing.

Comment: @CodeMed - My gut instinct is that this is a substitution cipher of some sort, translating these runes into an English translation of a short incantation from the Book of the Dead

Comment: I can believe that Tom Cruise et al would fail to pay that much attention to detail. Thank you and +1 for looking into it. Though perhaps someone else will find that there is an actual translation.

Comment: this definitely isn't Sumerian. Sumeria used cuneiform as it's writing system. The image you have there looks like aramaic?

Comment: I am thoroughly convinced of the fact that you have the names, numbers, addresses, emails, and knowledge of every single person of any import in this world, ever. Especially with this answer and the one about the Martian, just wow.

Comment: @Imperator - [Aw shucks](https://media3.giphy.com/media/YV1eoHooDmzC0/200_s.gif).

Comment: @1999mummyfan: Are you sure it's not just badly drawn cuneiform?

Answer (score 3):

The scriptures on Princess Ahmanet's face (Sofia Boutella) resembles that of the demotic or possibly [meroitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meroitic_alphabet) alphabet.

[image]

These writing systems are simplified variants of the Egyptian hieroglyphs, basically cursive versions of the hieroglyphs. The scriptures are taken from the manuscript "*Papyrus of Ani/Book of the Dead*" that contain [declarations and spells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Book_of_the_Dead_spells) to help the deceased in their afterlife. (for the actual hieroglyph plates [see here](https://zsitchinindex.wordpress.com/2016/03/15/the-book-of-the-dead-papyrus-of-ani/))

Unfortunately it's hard to decipher which scriptures are written on her face without a translated version of the "*Book of the Dead*" in one of the aforementioned writing systems.

Comment: I spotted that some of the symbols looked similar, but by the same token there are many that don't look anything like the symbols on her face.

Comment: Also, how do you know that the scriptures are taken from that particular papyrus manuscript? Is this just guesswork?

Comment: the video posted above (from 0:52) confirms the runes come from the "Book of the Dead".

Comment: Sure, but how do you know that they come from that particular version and that particular stanza?

Comment: Since there was no archetype yet many copies of the "Book of the Dead" were made, this too poses a problem to further correctly answer the question. And if I knew the particular stanza I would have directly answered the question.

Comment: @Valorum if you look at the demotic scripture [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/DemoticScriptsRosettaStoneReplica.jpg) you can find many of the missing symbols on her face.

Comment: My concern isn't over the matching symbols, it's over the ones (in fact that overwhelming majority) that don't match. On top of that, we know that the artist thinks that they're Sumerian, not Egyptian

Comment: When I googled the Sumerian alphabet and compared it to that of the symbols on her face, I personally felt that that couldn't be correct. After researching writing systems that derived from ancient Egypt, I found that demotic and meroitic closely resemble what's written on her face.

Comment: Some of them do, most of them don't. In fact, looking at them, about the same number match the modern Latin alphabet.

Comment: The Phoenician alphabet derived from Egyptian hieroglyphs became one of the most widely used writing systems spread across the Mediterranean world. The Greek alphabet (and by extension its descendants, such as Latin, and Coptic) was also derived from Phoenician. Interestingly, the Coptic alphabet are glyphs based on the Greek alphabet augmented by letters borrowed from the Egyptian Demotic and is the first alphabetic script used for the Egyptian language. So it could totally make sense if you see Latin looking letters there because the Egyptians were using an early form of it to write texts.

Answer (score -2):

It reminds me rather on the "Berber Alphabet" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Atlas_Tamazight

However I think the symbols on her face do not have any meaning. This movie is a generic Hollywood flick, the symbols were placed because they look cool.

Comment: Could you provide any evidence that it was just placed to look cool? or an image of what the Berber Alphabet looks like?